# cython error compiling with print function parameters

Tags: python-3.x, cython

when use cython to create helloworld.c from helloworld.pyx , this error occured:

```
    error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
print('hello world',end='')
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

p21.pyx:1:23: Expected ')', found '='
```

my command to create helloworld.c is:

```
cython3 --embed p21.pyx
```

Answer (score 21):

Cython is defaulting to Python 2 semantics. Set the language level to 3, which can be done with the following comment:

```
#cython: language_level=3
```

ref: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives

Answer (score 19):

It looks like cython treats all prints as python 2 statements by default. In order to use the python 3 print function you need to import it from the **future** module:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('hello world',end='')
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but in my case, with cython 0.23, to compile Python3 code you have to pass the flag `-3`. For example

```
cython -3 mycode.py
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer, because it does not require you to modify any source file.

Comment: In my opinion this is not the best answer because the language level to use is a property of the source file. It's much more robust to put it in the source file and then you'll never forget it on the command line

Comment: I agree, not the best option even if I suggested it as a possible solution.