# Why does Cython print in different format than Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

Simple question.

I have a file called printtest.py in Pythong 3.7.3 that contains one line of code:

```
print("Test", 1)
```

The result of importing it is:

```
Test 1
```

I then change the file to be printtest.pyx and change nothing else. I compile using Cython 0.29.12. Same single line of code. Now on importing I get:

```
('Test', 1)
```

Any time I use the print statement I get the extra parentheses and comma that I don't want. Why does it behave differently?

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185338/cython-error-compiling-with-print-function-parameters ?

Comment: looks like it's behaving like python 2 print, rather than python 3

Comment: Crap, you guys might be right. I didn't even know about the language level setting. I'll try that out.

Comment: I tried switching the language level and started getting a new error that is undoubtedly blocking me from truly verifying this: Unicode literals do not support coercion to C types other than Py_UNICODE/Py_UCS4 (for characters) or Py_UNICODE* (for strings).

Comment: However, that probably means you are all correct.

Comment: Okay, confirmed that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you're having problems with unicode you might want to look at the "3str" language level, which switches to Python 3 mode for everything but strings.