# Cython crashes calling print function

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython

I have a really simple `cython` code, built with `python3`

```sh
python3 setup.py build_ext
```

```py
cpdef public int say_hello ():
    print("HELLO")
    return 1
```

Which I call in a `C` program

```c
#include <Python.h>

Py_Initialize();
PyInit_libwrapper();
int ok = say_hello();
```

Here's the error i get

```sh
#0  0x00007fffeabebb52 in PyTuple_Pack () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
#1  0x00007fffea7eb8f1 in __Pyx_PrintOne (stream=0x0, o=<optimized out>) at code/cython/wrapper.c:2123
#2  0x00007fffea7eb8f1 in say_hello (__pyx_skip_dispatch=<optimized out>) at code/cython/wrapper.c:1114
```

If I don't call `print` function everything works fine, and also if I use `python2` (as follows) everything works fine

```sh
python2 setup.py build_ext
```

```c
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

Py_Initialize();
initlibwrapper();
int ok = say_hello();
```

Where's the problem?

**EDIT:**
Adding the comment

```py
#cython: language_level=3
```

I get a different error

```sh
say_hello (__pyx_skip_dispatch=0) at code/cython/wrapper.c:1106
1106      __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyObject_Call(__pyx_builtin_print, __pyx_tuple_, NULL); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 21, __pyx_L1_error)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffea7eb8cc in say_hello (__pyx_skip_dispatch=0) at code/cython/wrapper.c:1106
```

Comment: might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185338/cython-error-compiling-with-print-function-parameters
make sure cython defaults to python3

Comment: I edited adding one of the solutions